# UICollectionView header height animation

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have the following scenario...

When I initially load a UICollectionView, I need it to slide up from the bottom of the screen without a header. This is pretty easy.

There is an "Add" cell that takes the user through the process of adding an item. At the end of this process, we display the list again, but this time with a header. The header needs to fade in and, at the same time, the updated list slides up from the bottom.

The requirement is that the header scroll with the list after both are in place, which is pretty much the default behavior.

The problem I'm having is coming up with a workable method for animating the list slide while the header is displayed.

One thought is simply animating the height of the header. Basically, start it with a height equal to the view height, then animate it to its final size. This would automatically draw the rest of the list up, making it look as though it were sliding in.

I've tried several variations of this method with no success. I can set the height without a problem, but I haven't been able to animate it.

I had thought just returning the appropriate height from referenceSizeForHeaderInSection and reloading the data would handle it. At least that's what I gather from SO messages. I've also tried invalidating the layout and performBatchUpdates.

Would this be simpler if I placed the contents of my header in the first row of the collection view and then try animating the height of row 0?

I'm not sure which is the best strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the following which was easily adapted to my scenario...

[iOS Animating UITableView Header](https://michiganlabs.com/news/ios-animating-uitableview-header)

Here's a Wayback Machine link to the original post. It may take a little while to load. Be patient.

[Wayback Machine: iOS Animating UITableView Header](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108185958/https://michiganlabs.com/ios/development/2016/05/31/ios-animating-uitableview-header/)

And here's a GitHub link with sample code...

[GitHub: MichiganLabs / AnimatingTableViewHeader](https://github.com/MichiganLabs/AnimatingTableViewHeader)